# Do duplicate values in the JOIN key affect the result returned?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 queries that looks like this.

QUERY 1

```
    SELECT a.utype, DATE_TRUNC(b.date, DAY) AS date, (b.noofspec)
    FROM `table1`as a
    JOIN  `table2` as b
    ON a.joinkey = b.joinkey       
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY 2;
```

QUERY 2

```
    SELECT a.utype, DATE_TRUNC(b.date, DAY) AS date, SUM(b.noofspec)
    FROM `table1`as a
    JOIN  `table2` as b
    ON a.joinkey = b.joinkey       
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 2;
```

I am expecting that (b.noofspec) of QUERY 1 would somehow have a TOTAL with same value as SUM((b.noofspec). However, it returned a completely different value.

My tables looks like this

TABLE B

| gameid | date | noofspecs | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 50 | ID1 |
| 2 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 50 | ID2 |
| 3 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 58 | ID3 |
| 4 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 100 | ID4 |
| 5 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 555 | ID5 |
| 6 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 55 | ID6 |
| 7 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | 17 | ID7 |

TABLE A

| gameid | date | game | action | id | specid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | DOTA | to host | ID1 | ID58 |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:02 | LOL | to join1 | ID11 | ID24 |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:03 | DOTA | like | ID1 | ID87 |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:04 | DOTA | to host | ID1 | ID99 |
| 2 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | CSGO | to host | ID2 | ID47 |
| 2 | 2121-04-06 00:06 | DOTA | to join1 | ID21 | ID09 |
| 2 | 2121-04-06 00:10 | DOTA | to join2 | ID22 | ID23 |
| 3 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | LOL | to host | ID3 | ID77 |

What happens is that a user hosts a game(host), another user joins(join1, join2) and others can watch(counted in watch), spectators can send stars to the game if they want. just like in fb gaming and twitch. sender is listed in the specid, rcvr is in id which means that rcvr can also be not the host.

In Table B, gameid is unique. And also displays the host of the game.

In Table A, gameid returns activity results for a specific time.

For example, in row 1 of table a, viwer id58 sent star to host on  2121-04-06 00:01 for gameid 1 which is a dota game. the game column specifies what game is hosted so game id 1 is a dota game. but you may notice that in row 2 of table a, the game listed is LOL for the same game. that is because the game type listed is the game that gamer is streaming. in this case, ID11 is a LOL streamer who joined a DOTA game.

| gameid | date | game | action | id | specid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:01 | DOTA | to host | ID1 | ID58 |
| 1 | 2121-04-06 00:02 | LOL | to join1 | ID11 | ID24 |

The result I am expecting is that I get a SUM of all the views of each type of game per day.  I used gameid as the joining key but I think it complicates the result because of the duplicate entries in gameid tablea. I also tried with the using id as a joining key but the problem is the result is also aggregating the join userids.

One more problem I find is that in id column of table a, when someone send a like to the game, it goes to the host. so i have two unique columns if i group them and filtered joins. one for the like and one for the tohost.

Comment: I think the second should return an error, because the third column is a `SUM()` and that is not suitable for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ill edit that. That should not be there.

Comment: 1) Please add the table data to your question as editable text, not as linked images 2) Based on the data in the 2 tables, please provide the result that you want to achieve

Comment: Changes were added now. I tried my best to make it clearer. I hope it did that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two queries are very different; your first query will return a set of values that is distinct, your second will sum a set that is not distinct

Let us demonstrate with simpler data:

```
A.X, A.Y
1, 100
2, 200

B.X
1
1
1
2
2
```

Let us join the tables:

```
SELECT A.X, A.Y, B.X
FROM A JOIN B ON A.X = B.X
```

The result:

```
1, 100, 1
1, 100, 1
1, 100, 1
2, 200, 2
2, 200, 2
```

The first two columns come from A, the third from B

Joining B in has caused A’s rows to repeat. They would still repeat even if you didn’t select B; the repetition is caused by the join

This is all fine until you want to sum up Y

```
SELECT A.X, SUM(A.Y) FROM A JOIN B ON A.X = B.X GROUP BY A.X

1, 300
2, 400
```

The repetitions are included in the sum

So why was it different to your first query?

Your first query grouped all the columns, effectively squishing the generated duplicates

```
SELECT A.X, A.Y, B.X
FROM A JOIN B ON A.X = B.X 
GROUP BY A.X, A.Y, B.X
```

The select and from lines above are the original query I first wrote in this answer; they generate 5 rows, 3 rows of 1,100.1 and 2 rows of 2,200,2

The group by squishes them back to only unique rows, the sum of Y would hence be very different because there are no duplicated values taking part in the sum

Comment: ps; in terms of what to do about it - if we want to join some table in that will cause duplicates, and we want a unique set of results, we group the incoming table before we join (so that it too has unique join columns), so that it doesn't cause duplication.. This might also mean doing SUMs before we join